# process Android image with opencv

Tags: android, opencv, android-image

I have this code :

```
protected Bitmap processFrame(byte[] data) {
    Mat mat = new Mat(mFrameHeight, mFrameWidth, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    mat.put(0, 0, data);

    //process mat with native code

    Utils.matToBitmap(mat, mBitmap);

    return mBitmap;
}


private Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Bitmap bmp = processFrame(data);

        if (bmp != null) {
            //draw bmp
        }
    }
};
```

at some point I define the bitmap as:

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

The result is the same camera frames captured but in gray scale repeated 3 times horizontally, I tried CvType.CV_8UC4 and they are repeated 4 times instead.

I need to display the whole image as is using the same steps

Does anybody catch the mistake ??

Comment: sounds like it's not copying for some reason. Why are you not using the code from the samples? They give you the infrastructure for all this. Look for the JavaCameraView file.

Comment: I already have the android application built and just need to integrate opencv in side, what do you think could be the cause of this behaviour ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changed this method .. it is solved ..

```
protected Bitmap processFrame(byte[] data) {

    Mat mYuv = new Mat( mFrameHeight + mFrameHeight/2, mFrameWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    mYuv.put(0, 0, data);

    Mat mRGB = new Mat();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuv, mRGB, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21, 3);

    ProcessFrame(mRGB.getNativeObjAddr(), mRGB.width(), mRGB.height());

    Utils.matToBitmap(mRGB, mBitmap);

    return mBitmap;
}
```